# Block Element Characters in Python 3 Module Docstring

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I'm writing the description docstring for a module for Python 3 and I'm trying to include the following characters "█╗ ╔═║╝╚–". On Linux, this works just fine, but the same code on Windows prints their Unicode references instead e.g. "\u2588" etc. What can I do to correct the behaviour on Windows?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
I want to use these characters █╗ ╔═║╝╚–
"""

# foo module
pass
```

Desired behaviour:

```
>>> import fooModule
>>> help(fooModule)
Help on module fooModule:

NAME
    fooModule

DESCRIPTION
    I want to use these characters █╗ ╔═║╝╚–

[etc]
```

Many thanks for any help rendered!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug where `help()` is using the ANSI code page to determine printable characters, but the Windows console is using the OEM code page.  If you use the `Windows-1252`-equivalent characters for the Windows console's OEM encoding `cp437` in the source code, then the Windows console displays them correctly (Python 3.8):

```py
def f():
    """
    I want to use these characters Û» ÉÍº¼È
    """
    pass

help(f)
print('Û» ÉÍº¼È█╗ ╔═║╝╚')
```

Output (Windows console):

```
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    I want to use these characters █╗ ╔═║╝╚

Û» ÉÍº¼È█╗ ╔═║╝╚
```

Note that a UTF-8-capable IDE displays the characters as specified.  Even changing the Windows console code page via `chcp 1252` continues to display them incorrectly.  Somewhere in the help rendering process an encode/decode is being performed incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm a little unsure as how to implement your solution. Are you saying that I can replace the character with a different one that will work instead (I tried copying what you did above, but it produced the same result as my previous efforts), or that I need to change the character encoding of the string? If I have to change the terminal settings to view the docstring correctly, that can't work as a solution, as I can't expect the end user to change their settings just for my program.

Comment: @Mark Its more of an explanation than a solution. I don’t recommended using non-ASCII characters in the doc string if you expect them to be read correctly at the Windows console

Comment: Ah, well thank you regardless. It always seems that whether I have to do anything involving special characters in Python, it's Windows that makes my life difficult. I'll have to do things a bit differently to how I'd planned. If I do later encounter a solution, I'll update the thread accordingly.

Comment: Update: I came up with a work around, which I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- so I found a work around of sorts. I was already using `platform.system()` to read the user's operating system. As such, now if the program detects that it is running on Windows, it makes a substitution of the problem characters:

```
from platform import system

if system() == 'Windows':
    # Windows doesn't let us have nice things in our docstrings
    __doc__ = __doc__.replace('█', '#')
    __doc__ = __doc__.replace('–', '--')
    for r in '╗╔═║╝╚':
        __doc__ = __doc__.replace(r, ' ')
```

This means that anyone viewing the code in a text editor will still see the docstring as intended, as will anyone using `help()` on Linux or MacOS. Windows users will get an inferior experience, but the docstring will at least be legible to them.

Comment: Note that using the wrong characters is a `help()` issue with Windows cmd.exe.  Using an IDE that supports UTF-8 will display correctly, so this solution might work in cmd.exe, but break other Python environments.  Better to stick with ASCII on Windows, or detect specifically running in cmd.exe.

Comment: I'll see if I can test for the shell type; it looks like `psutil` might be useful for that. On Windows, I'm using PowerShell by the way. I'll update again at a later date, as it's late here.

Incidently, are there any non-Windows cases where I could expect to have this problem?

Comment: I tested powershell and it has the same issue as cmd.exe (it still uses the text console), but for IDEs (I tested with PythonWin from the pywin32 module) it worked correctly.  I suppose Linux could have the issue if its terminal wasn't configured for UTF-8.  Another reason to stick to ASCII.

Comment: >>> I suppose Linux could have the issue if its terminal wasn't configured for UTF-8 --- Is there a simple way to test the configuration of the terminal from within Python? I've not found anything thus far. (hello again, I'm back from holiday)